# Canvas with VisualBrush not rendering Image correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I've got a Canvas that I'm setting the Background property to a VisualBrush consisting of an Image. I'm data binding the Canvas' Width and Height to the Images' Width and Height. Here's the XAML:

```
            <Canvas x:Name="imageCanvas" ClipToBounds="True" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dataImage}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dataImage}"
                Loaded="imageCanvas_Loaded" MouseMove="imageCanvas_MouseMove">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Image x:Name="dataImage" ClipToBounds="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding DataImage, Mode=OneWay}" LayoutTransform="{Binding DataImageLayoutTransform, Mode=OneWay}"/> 
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
```

Note that Image is using a LayoutTransform. I'm using this to stretch the width of the image. If I disable the LayoutTransform binding and run I get the following (properly) rendered output:

[image]

However, when I add the LayoutTransform to stretch the width of the image by a factor of 6, the image looks stretched correctly but it is too small i.e. it is not filling the Canvas uniformly:

[image]

I suspect this may have something to do with binding the Canvas Height/Width to the image height width, but it's not clear what the exact problem is. Can anyone provide some insight? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a VisualBrush with an Image element, instead of a far simpler ImageBrush?

Comment: @Clemens - I need to support zoom/pan behavior within a ScrollViewer and found the following code worked very nicely: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/97871/wpf-simple-zoom-and-drag-support-in-a-scrollviewer  That code uses a VisualBrush with an Image visual. I didn't anticipate the odd behavior when applying a LayoutTransform however. Can you elaborate on how I would replace the current strategy with an ImageBrush?

Comment: Elaborating on that would mean that I would read and try to understand the code in that codproject article, and then guess how you might have adapted it to your application. If you are looking for help here, you're supposed to show a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'll prepare a "skeletal" example and post soon. Thank you!

Comment: Please see the following new post for a "bare bones" example of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228655/data-binding-to-actualheight-width-fails-with-layouttransform