# How can I update the contents of a TransformedBitmap?

Tags: wpf, writeablebitmap

I'm using a TransformedBitmap in my WPF application to stretch a WriteableBitmap. I need to update the WriteableBitmap and then transform it as the user moves a slider control. Currently I'm instantiating a new TransformedBitmap every time the slider is manipulated:

```
TransformedBitmap transformedBitmap = new TransformedBitmap(myWriteableBitmap, myTransform);
```

Updating the WriteableBitmap is very fast but creating a new TransformedBitmap each time is impacting performance. Can anyone suggest some improvements?

Comment: Why do you need to do this at all? Instead of for example applying the Transform to the RenderTransform property of an Image element that displays the WriteableBitmap.

Comment: @Clemens - This is an attempt to bypass the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173376/canvas-with-visualbrush-not-rendering-image-correctly?noredirect=1#comment91297639_52173376

Comment: That's what I figured. So I ask again, why aren't you using an ImageBrush? That said, a VisualBrush or ImageBrush has a viewport and a viewbox which allows you to precisely control which part of it is actually drawn. A TransformedBitamp is the least thing you need. If you would add some details about what exactly you are actually trying to achieve in the other post or here, we may perhaps provide some help.

Comment: I've updated the other post with some more information.