# Data binding to ActualHeight/Width fails with LayoutTransform

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Consider the following simple XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
    <Rectangle Stroke="Red" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dataImage}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dataImage}">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image x:Name="dataImage" ClipToBounds="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Stretch="Uniform" Source="c:\Moray.png"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This generates the following output:

[image]

Now, I add a layout transform to the above XAML to get:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
    <Rectangle Stroke="Red" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dataImage}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dataImage}">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image x:Name="dataImage" ClipToBounds="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Stretch="Uniform" Source="c:\Moray.png">
                        <Image.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="6"/>
                        </Image.LayoutTransform>
                    </Image>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The result is:

[image]

It seems like the Rectangle Height/Width properties which are data bound to the image Actualheight/ActualWidth properties are not altering to respect the new image aspect ratio as a result of the LayoutTransform applied to the image. The Rectangle is still expressing the pre-transformed aspect ratio. Why is this and how can I achieve behavior such that the Rectangle adjusts itself according to the images transformed dimensions as I intended with the binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout doesn't work out of the box with Brushes.

When you assign a LayoutTransform to the Visual in a VisualBrush it doesn't impact the layout of the element that's filled with the Brush. You would instead have to assign the LayoutTransform to the Rectange instead if the Image. However, that would also stretch the Rectangle's Stroke.

Better don't use a VisualBrush at all, but just an Image in an appropriate parent element, e.g. a Border. This would also avoid the need for binding to the Image's ActualWidth and ActualHeight.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="C:\Moray.png">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="6"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```